# Kafka KTables missing data when joining KStream to KTable

Tags: join, apache-kafka, missing-data, apache-kafka-streams

Has anyone posted a response to this problem?  There have been other posts with no answers. Our situation is that we are pushing messages onto a topic that is backing a KTable in the first step of our stream process.  We are then pulling a small amount of data from those messages and passing them along.  We are doing multiple computations on that smaller amount of data for grouping and aggregation.  At the end of the streaming process, we simply want to join back to that original topic via a KTable to pick up the full message content again.  The results of the join are only a subset of the data because it can not find the entries in the KTable.

This is just the beginning of the problem.  In another case, we are using KTables as indexes for lookups meant to enrich the data coming in.  Think of these lookups as identifying whether we have seen a specific pattern in the streaming message before.  If we have seen the pattern we want to tag it with an ID (used for grouping) pulled from an existing KTable.  If we have not seen the pattern before we would assign it an ID and place it back into the KTable to be used to tag future messages.  What we have found is that there is no guaranty that the information will be present in the KTable for future messages.  This lack of guaranty seems to make KTables useless.  We can not figure out why there is a very little discussion of this on the forums.

Finally, none of this seemed to be a problem when running with a single instance of the streams application.  However, as soon as our data got large and we were forced to have 10 instances of the app, everything broke.  As well, there is no way that we could use things like GlobalKTables because there is too much data to be loaded into a single machine's memory.

What can we do?  We are currently planning to abandon KTables all together and use something like Hazelcast to store the lookup data.  Should we just move to Hazelcast Jet and drop Kafka streams all together?

Adding flow:
[Kafka data flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqbUK.png)

Comment: It's a little unclear from the question what you actually try to do and what the problem could be. I can only tell you that Kafka Streams is used by many companies in production and it works for them. However, statements like "everything broke" are super general and (at least) I don't know how to approach the question. I would recommend you share some code and minimal data examples that describe the problem. Otherwise, I doubt that you will a good answer.

Comment: I have added an Image showing the flow.  The Join in the red group is the one that is not returning all of the messages from the Person KTable.  The behavior is simple.  The behavior is: 1) when the join starts it finds all the persons in the KTable, 2) as it goes along there start to be a few nulls for person, 3) the longer it runs through the 500 Million Person records the more nulls return, 4) by end of run there are only nulls in join results for person

Comment: The diagram only show one input for the join. That is confusion. A join should have `KTable` input and a `KStream` input. Also, from the flow you describe, could it be that persons get deleted from the `KTable`?

Comment: The diagram shows a flow of a message being consumed from the "Person w/ Neighbo(r)hood" streaming topic to be joined with the Person KTable topic.  The "Person" topic is not modified other than the original inserts.  It is only joined to.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry for this non-answer answer, but I don't have enough points to comment...

The behavior you describe is definitely inconsistent with my understanding and experience with streams. If you can share the topology (or a simplified one) that is causing the problem, there might be a simple mistake we can point out.

Once we get more info, I can edit this into a "real" answer...

Thanks!
-John

Comment: I have added an Image showing the flow.  The Join in the red group is the one that is not returning all of the messages from the Person KTable.  The behavior is simple.  The behavior is: 1) when the join starts it finds all the persons in the KTable, 2) as it goes along there start to be a few nulls for person, 3) the longer it runs through the 500 Million Person records the more nulls return, 4) by end of run there are only nulls in join results for person